# Error installing Opennms on Oracle Linux 6.9

Tags: software-installation, yum, postgresql, oracle-linux

I need to install Opennms monitoring software because I'm getting error trying to install it on Oracle Linux 6.9.

I used this commands:

```
wget https://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/pgdg-oraclelinux93-9.3-3.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql93-server postgresql93-contrib uuid-pgsql.x86_64 repmgr93.x86_64 rhdb-utils.x86_64 skytools-93-modules.x86_64 pgbackrest.x86_64 pgdg-oraclelinux93.noarch pgloader.x86_64 pgmemcache-93.x86_64 pgmp93.x86_64 phpPgAdmin.noarch pgagent_93.x86_64 ora2pg.noarch -y
```

Then, with sudo rights did:

```
sudo bash bootstrap-yum.sh
```

And getting the error below:

```
PostgreSQL initialize                 ... FAILED
```

I'm using the installer provided by [official site](https://www.opennms.org/en/install-centos).

Comment: I successfully installed Opennms and got the service to start but I did it on CentOS 7.5 and it took a lot of rigmarole. I can post what I did as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Oks, yes, please, show me the steps under Centos 7.5. As well, I want also setting up an Opennms under OL 6.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to install it and get the service start on CentOS 7.5. It's probably best that you completely remove Opennms and Postresql before you begin. I did this by running as root.

Beforehand, make sure that you have the following `java` packages installed:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
java-1.8.0-openjdk-src
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless
javapackages-tools
jdk
jdk1.8.0_144
```

I installed some of these packages when I got the end of this and the setup was giving me errors so you can wait until you get to the Java part at the bottom if you can't install them at this point due to the opennms repos not being available.

First, I created a directory at `/opt/opennms` and then downloaded a tar.gz inside and decompressed it using the instructions in this link(I used `wget` instead of `curl -L`:

https://www.opennms.org/en/install-centos

```
wget https://github.com/opennms-forge/opennms-install/archive/1.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz 1.2.tar.gz
cd opennms-install-1.2
bash bootstrap-yum.sh
```

I went through the same steps that you did and got the same error so I then went to the link to the installation guide:

https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/latest/guide-install/guide-install.html#gi-install-opennms-rhel

`Postgresql` and `Opennms` were already installed so I skipped again to the part about setting up `Postresql`(I created a different name for the user but it really doesn't matter):

Enable and start `postgresql` service

```
systemctl enable postgresql
systemctl start postgresql
su - postgres
```

Create database user:

```
createuser -P opennms
createdb -O opennms opennms
exit
```

Create password for Postgresql super user where `YOUR-POSTGRES-PASSWORD` is a password of your choosing.

```
su - postgres
psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'YOUR-POSTGRES-PASSWORD';"
exit
```

To allow access over the local network:

```
vim /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Be sure that the file looks like this:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Afterwards:

```
systemctl restart postgresql
```

Next, alter the database configuration:

```
vim ${OPENNMS_HOME}/etc/opennms-datasources.xml
```

Make sure it looks like below as there may be some differently formatted text for the username and/or password:

```
<jdbc-data-source name="opennms"
database-name="opennms"
class-name="org.postgresql.Driver"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/opennms"
user-name="** YOUR-OPENNMS-USERNAME **"
password="** YOUR-OPENNMS-PASSWORD **" />

<jdbc-data-source name="opennms-admin"
database-name="template1"
class-name="org.postgresql.Driver"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/template1"
user-name="postgres"
password="** YOUR-POSTGRES-PASSWORD **" />`
```

You can install the `java` and `jdk` packages I listed above at this point if you didn't already.

Initialize `Opennms`:

```
{OPENNMS_HOME}/bin/runjava -s
{OPENNMS_HOME}/bin/install -dis
```

If the `OPENNMS_HOME` variable isn't set, it is equal to `/opt/opennms` or you can run the commands with the full paths:

```
/opt/opennms/bin/run/java -s
/opt/opennms/bin/run/install -dis
```

You may get some error messages but if everything went well, you'll be okay. There should be a file created to confirm:

```
/opt/opennms/etc/configured
```

Lastly:

```
systemctl enable opennms
systemctl start opennms
```

If that starts up with no errors then you're done.

This may not work exactly for you as it did for me and you might have to modify a few things but hopefully this gives you some headway.